# How to launch a new SPL Token on Strata launchpad

Tags: token

I tried to create a new utility SPL token and launch on mainet but it seems like I am missing some steps.
I try https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad/fully-managed/new to connect a panthom wallet but then it doesn't proceed further.

I also tried to see a demo on https://token-creator-lac.vercel.app/ , similar problem when I wanted to connect a panthom wallet.

Comment: I tried connecting to the launchpad and didnt get any error. Can you explain more on what is the error exactly ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the chromo pop up blocker was blocking the extension.